# GLSL shading problem: Why is my sphere in greyscale instead of red? (see code)

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl, lighting

I'm working on a beginner level GLSL shader program. I'm following [this](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/articles/article.asp?article=21) tutorial. But my sphere always appear in greyscale and not colored red as I expected.

Vertex Shader:

```
varying vec3 normal, lightDir;

void main() {

    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;

    normal = gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal;

    vec4 vertex_in_modelview_space = gl_ModelViewMatrx * gl_Vertex;

    lightDir = vec3(gl_LightSource[0].position – vertex_in_modelview_space);

}
```

Frag Shader:

```
varying vec3 normal, lightDir;

void main()
{

    const vec4 AmbientColor = vec4(0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    const vec4 DiffuseColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    vec3 normalized_normal = normalize(normal);
    vec3 normalized_lightDir = normalize(lightDir);

    float DiffuseTerm = clamp(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0, 1.0);
    gl_FragColor = AmbientColor + DiffuseColor * DiffuseTerm;
}
```

The code is just copy and paste off the tutorial.

From the frag shader, the diffuse color is red, but my sphere is greyscale. I know that the shaders are loaded correctly though because if I take out the code in the frag shader and use the following:

gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0);

then my sphere is solid green as expected. I do not know if it's something in the openGL code (like, Renderer.cpp) that's causing a conflict, or if there's something else wrong.

This is my first time coding in GLSL, and I'm quite confused about what gl_Enable's I need to turn on/off for the shader to work properly.

Thanks for any feedback!

**EDIT:**
Ok, if I call glColor3f before rendering, I can get the right color. But doesn't the light's color directly result in a change of color in the sphere? I'm worried that I'm not actually calling the functions in the shader...

**EDIT2:**
So it turns out that whenever I put any code in the vertex shader or frag shader (other than gl_Color = ...), the solid color I get disappears... I guess this means that there's something horribly wrong with my shaders?

**EDIT3:**
Here's the code for setting up my shader (supplied by my TA):

```
char *vs = NULL,*fs = NULL;

v = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

f = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

vs = textFileRead(vert);
fs = textFileRead(frag);

const char * ff = fs;
const char * vv = vs;

glShaderSource(v, 1, &vv,NULL);
glShaderSource(f, 1, &ff,NULL);

free(vs);
free(fs);

glCompileShader(v);
glCompileShader(f);

p = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(p,f);
glAttachShader(p,v);

glLinkProgram(p);

int infologLength = 0;
int charsWritten  = 0;
char *infoLog;

glGetProgramiv(p, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH,&infologLength);
if (infologLength > 0)
{
    infoLog = (char *)malloc(infologLength);
    glGetProgramInfoLog(p, infologLength, &charsWritten, infoLog);
    printf("%s\n",infoLog);
    free(infoLog);
}
```

**EDIT4:**
Using shader logs as suggested by kvark, I managed to fix the bugs in the shaders (turns out there were a couple of mistakes). If you would like to see the final code, please leave a comment or message me (this question is getting long).

Comment: w.r.t. EDIT2: Do you check for errors from shader compilation/setup? There are specific GL calls to get such output for shaders.

Comment: What version of GL are you targeting?

Comment: Tommy: I'm coding in Ubuntu. How can I find out what version of GL I have?

Comment: Marcus: in Edit 3, at the bottom of the shaders setup, there's a call to glGetProgramInfoLog. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: What does the varying `diffuse` do?  You don't write to it in the vertex shader, and it isn't read from in the fragment shader.

Comment: Brad: It was something I forgot to comment out after all the different tutorials I tried to follow, sorry. I don't believe it would do anything to affect the code though. Edit: yup, commented it out, but the results are the same.

Comment: @confusedKid. You should edit your question to account for questions or suggestions, I asked myself the question about your `diffuse` varying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good idea to check not just the link log, but also compile logs for each shader and compile/link result:

```
glGetShaderInfoLog(...)
glGetShaderiv(...,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,...)
glGetProgramiv(...,GL_LINK_STATUS,...)
```

Make sure the results are positive and the logs are empty (or good).

The diffuse term is calculated incorrectly in your example. It should have the following value:

```
float DiffuseTerm = max(0.0, dot(normalized_normal,normalized_lightDir) );
```

You don't need clamp() as the dot() result of normalized vectors can't exceed 1.

If you made sure the shader program is linked correctly, activated it on a draw and the result is still weird, try to select different components of your final color equation to find out the wrong one:

```
gl_FragColor = DiffuseColor;       //can't be grayscale
gl_FragColor = vec4(DiffuseTerm);  //should be diffuse grayscale
```

BTW, glColor3f should have nothing to do with your shader as you don't use gl_Color inside. If the result changes when you call it - that would mean the shader activation failed (it didn't link or wasn't used at all).

Good Luck!

Comment: where should I put the glGetShaderInfoLog, etc? Where I initialize the shaders?

Comment: @kvark. Why are you saying that the diffuse term is incorrect ? It may be suboptimal, but the results obtained are the same as those of your formulation ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: @confuseKid. put glGetShaderiv(..) and glGetShaderInfoLog(..) after you call glCompileShader() for each shader. And don't forget to check the values returned as compile/link status

Comment: @rotoglup. Yes, of course they are different. By calling dot() on non-normalized vectors you'll get some huge values, which will be clamped to 0 and 1, making the final result to be almost monochrome. And what would be the point to normalize those vectors and not use them afterwards? :)

Comment: @kvark. The OP's shader uses normalized vectors, and clamps values, I don't follow you sorry.

Comment: @rotoglup: `clamp(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0, 1.0)` - which vectors you see normalized here?

Comment: @kvark. OK see it now, I missed the fact that the `normalize` results are assigned to unused variables :P

Answer (score 0):

*Maybe* it's due to an unwanted behaviour with your alpha channel result.

You're actually computing lighting on your alpha channel, actually having something like : g

> gl_FragColor.a = 1.0 + 1.0 * DiffuseTerm

which will give you >= 1.0 values.

You should be careful not to include your alpha channel in your output (or even in your calculations).

Try making sure your blending is disabled, or fix your shader to something like :

```
varying vec3 normal, lightDir;

void main()
{
    const vec3 AmbientColor = vec3(0.1, 0.0, 0.0);
    const vec3 DiffuseColor = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    vec3 normalized_normal = normalize(normal);
    vec3 normalized_lightDir = normalize(lightDir);

    float DiffuseTerm = clamp(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0, 1.0);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(AmbientColor + DiffuseColor * DiffuseTerm, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested, but there was no difference in the results. Thanks for the tips though.